# Advanced procedures using the Median statistic

Tags: median, model

With the risk of asking a duplicate question (to be fair, I looked at 10 pages):
Could you name and explain some advanced procedures which make use of the median statistic?

Background: I am interested because today I saw a presentation on a TAR model, trying to figure out a baseline for negative affect within observants. The mean was taken as frequentist approach and also a Bayesian approach was done. My point was that median might be better, since if for some reason a person, when happy, is REALLY happy, while when sad would not be so different from a baseline. The mean would then not be a good estimate and I figured the median would be better?

EDIT: Maybe easier to comprehend: For which computations are medians used beyond simple descriptive statistics (and why is better than taking the mean for example)?

Comment: Welcome to the site, @Dualinity. I appreciate your having read some of the prior threads 1st, & trying to work within the standards of SE. I'm not sure I follow your question yet. You want advanced procedures that use the median, but advanced procedures to do what, exactly? In general, the median is maximally robust to outliers, but is also much less efficient. OTOH, for a distribution that is naturally skewed, whether the median is better than the mean will depend on what you want to do / know.

Comment: I just want to explore other descriptive statistics compared to the mean, and am trying to develop an understanding of when median's would be better. I would basically be looking for any kind of statistical model that uses the median? Like a linear regression model for instance. 

Your comment actually really makes sense. What does efficient mean in that sense though? And what about median and a normal distribution?

Comment: Also I would like to add that I am interested in non-parametric ways (not assuming any distribution) and I hoped maybe the median could be of use in that area.

Comment: Hi @Dualinity - with many thousands of questions here, you find previous questions similar to yours by using the search box to look for keywords related to your question, rather than by paging through previous questions. (If you mean you looked through 10 pages of results after a search, my apologies.)

Comment: @Glen_b That is exactly what I did. Don't worry about it, I understand your concern.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Quantile regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile_regression) might be an example of what you are looking for.  Traditional least-squares regression is implicitly approximating the conditional **mean** of your predicted variable, but quantile regression is instead approximating the conditional **median** (or really any desired quantile).  By not squaring the deviations, quantile regression treats outliers differently than techniques which rely upon squaring the deviations.  Of course whether this is a good thing or not depends upon what one is trying to do.

It's tough to tell, but I think perhaps in your case you are dealing with a scenario involving some [asymmetric loss function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_function).  Common loss functions (that often have nice mathematical properties) often treat overestimates the same as underestimates, but this need not be the case in a particular domain.  Asymmetric loss functions can reflect this reality.

Answer (score 3):

As indicated by @gung, the way your question is asked, there can be many answers. 
Of course that can be an opportunity and let me take it.

First you will likely will want to decide if it’s the median of the probability generating process you think should be modelled (REALLY happy comment) as opposed to using the  sample median to learn whatever you can about the  probability generating process (non-parametric ways comment).

I’ll focus on the second and start with a situation (that my Phd thesis was about) where you have no choice - because rather than getting the actual data you just get a summary of it from someone else. Bayes is immediate as you now condition the prior on that observation you got  (the sample median) which is all you have and the only tricky part is working out the likelihood for some assumed probability data model  - which is trivial if the number in the sample was odd –

p(x=sample median) * p( trunk(n/2) of x,s < sample median) *  p( trunk(n/2) of x,s > sample median).

From the frequentist perspective you can use the same likelihood or some approximation it. So it can apply to *any* statistical model and usually there is more to the summary than just the median.

Now if you are interested, Steve MacEachern has started looking at choosing to just use robust summaries in Bayesian analyses even when you do have all the raw data. You should be able to find an abstract from this summer’s Joint  Statistical Meetings in San Diego.

Partial answer to the question below from @Dualinity:

Actually, no because the authors had taken one of those introductory stats courses (and maybe even checked here) and became convinced that the *mean* was an invalid summary to provide. Now there is a rigorous way to rank sample summaries with respect to *capturing* the information content of a sample and here the mean will beat the median for most assumed probability models.

But even some statisticians are so convinced the median has better properties that when I started to go into this in a seminar, the senior statistician dismissed the arguments before I gave them and starting talking to people around him about other things.  I have perused some of the related entries and they seem to miss the distinction between population parameters and sample statistics (e.g. why it’s not always the case that the sample median is the *best* estimate of the population median) as well as distinguishing the purposes (e.g. describing the population or sample versus inference or learning about a population).

Fisher said it best a long time ago: “Best for what?”

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Q: When you get the summary from someone else, you would generally also get the mean though? I do not see how the median would then be preferred?

Comment: @Dualinity: I have appended a bit to my answer above. Still thinking about how to answer the question more generally (and find the time to do that).